# How to find out that a matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Since somebody here told me that it is in general insufficient to show that a matrix is positive definite when all eigenvalues are positive. I am interested in finding good ways to prove this. In general, it might be hard to verify the definition. So, I am looking for different ways to do this. Probably, I should point out that if you have an answer that works only in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces, I would highly appreciate such remarks too.

Thanks in advance!

Because the question came up what I mean by positive definite: No, I do not assume a positive definite matrix to be necessarily hermitian and Yes I want to have a fast way to see that a given matrix is positive definite.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is efficient but did you heard of Sylvester criterion ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: Your first sentence is confused (in particular the use of _insufficient_). A square real symmetric (or more generally complex Hermitian) matrix is positive definite *if and only if* all its eigenvalues are positive http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations. Are you trying to (dis?)prove this, or looking for a more practical criterion?

Comment: This depends on the definition of the positive definiteness. Considering complex matrices, do you require them to be Hermitian? If so, then having positive eigenvalues is equivalent to the matrix being positive definite. In such a case, the mentioned Sylvester criterion and/or an attempt to perform a Cholesky factorization work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Hermitian matrix (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) it is indeed necessary and sufficient that all eigenvalues are positive in order for the matrix to be positive definite, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations . I haven't heard of positive definite used to describe any operator that is not Hermitian.  It is easy to check that a matrix is Hermitian. If you don't want to compute all eigenvalues to verify they're positive, you can use Sylvester's criterion instead. It says that a Hermitian matrix is positive definite is all upper-left blocks (including the full matrix) have positive determinants. The link also gives other characterizations, but they may be harder to check in practice.

Comment: "The link also gives other characterizations, but they may be harder to check in practice." Obviously it depends on what "in practice" means, Sylvester is practical only on tiny hand-made calculations.

Comment: Sure, I usually think in terms of what a computer can do. Computing determinants is fairly easy to code up and pretty fast to run on a computer if an efficient technique like row reduction is used.

Comment: Yep, row reduction without pivoting (row/column permutations) can be used and break it down after the first occurrence of a non-positive pivot with the conclusion that the matrix is not positive definite. No determinants needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -10 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Both of its eigenvalues equal 1, but it is not positive definite, since
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -10 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= -8
\end{equation}
There $ are $ positive definite matrices which are not symmetric (hermitian), for example
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 & x_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  -1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=x_1^2 + x_2^2
\end{equation}

Comment: It can't be checked by Sylvester's criterion because it holds only for symmetric/Hermitian matrices. With such a criterion, even the first mentioned matrix would be "positive definite".

Comment: Fixed it. Here is an explicit proof

Comment: It could be also checked by applying Mr. Sylvester to the Hermitian part of $A$: $H=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^*)$, because $x^*Ax=x^*Hx$ (a $H$ is Hermitian). Nevertheless, the author should first state what his definition of positive definiteness is :-) BTW non-Hermitian p.d. matrices are sometimes called "positive stable" or "positive real".